# Interaction between variables to create a ranking system

Tags: pca, z-score, ranks, rating

I was wondering if there is a standard way to rank cases by multiple variables.

When we have only 1 quantitative variable, the ranking is trivial, you sort the cases by comparing the magnitude between cases, ordering them by that value in increasing or decreasing order. Because there is only one component, this ranking is always correct.

When there is more than one variable, the answer is not that clear.

Let's take the example of olympic weightlifting. In olympic weightlifting, each participant performs two distinct lifts, the snatch and the clean&jerk (there are 3 attempts per lift but let's ignore that for simplicity's sake). Within a weight class, the participants are ranked by the total weight lifted, that is, the ordering is done by simply adding the two lifts.

The problem with this is that it fails to consider that the weights usually lifted in each lift differ (is much harder to lift 1kg more in the snatch than it is in the C&J). A workaround to this would be to calculate the Z-scores for each lift so they are comparable, but still, there are many ways by which you could perform an ordering.

These are the techniques I have explored:

- Adding Z-Scores.
- Multiplying Z-Scores (adding a constant to each one to avoid problems with signs).
- Calculating the minimum of both variables Z-Scores.
- Performing principal component analysis and sorting by the component with shared variance in the same direction for both variables.
- Creating new variables, 1 for each old variable, that holds the ordinal position of each case when all cases are sorted by that variable (for example, the case with the heaviest snatch and second heaviest C&J would have the values 1 and 2 in the respective new variables). With these new variables you could try using any of the previous methods again (adding them, multiplying them etc).
- Do all of this and then calculate PCA again.

What method for sorting will tend to be the least wrong in general? Also, as a sidenote, what's the difference between adding and multiplying 2 Z-Scores (after correcting for sign)?

**Edit**:
What about representing each case with Z-scores in a graph, and then calculate the euclidean distance to the theoretical right upermost limit? The equation would be something like this:

$d_{i} = {\sqrt{(max(v_{1})-v_{1i})^{2}+(max(v_{2})-v_{2i})^{2}\ldots(max(v_{n})-v_{ni})^{2}}}$

Comment: My go-to is the [geometric mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_mean#Calculation), but other people may have different ideas.

Comment: @Escherichia You just made me discover the pythagorean means. Thanks, this can be very useful.

Comment: These methods, being *ad hoc,* will not assure you of reaching any effective solution, nor will any variation of them.  For a principled approach that has been applied to real problems, see our [posts on multi-attribute valuation theory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=attribute%20multi*%20valuation).

Comment: @whuber I'll give it a read